# Delayed Jobs and Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am having trouble with implementing delayed jobs with my ActionMailer:
Before Delayed Job Implementation:

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "noreply@mycompany.com"
  default :to => "info@mycompany.com"

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(:subject => "[Company Notification] #{message.subject}")
  end

end
```

and called it using this line (it worked perfectly fine):

```
NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
```

---

After the Delayed Job implementation all i did was change the deliver line to:

```
NotificationsMailer.delay.new_message(@message)
```

In addition, I started the jobs queue using

```
rake jobs:work
```

I can see the objects in the database if the job is closed and i can see they get popped after i start the worker but nothing happens (no email sent).

Update - Other Delayed Tasks (not related to mail) are working fine.

Can anyone help a newbie?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: are you working development environment?
check out inside the config, perhaps action_mailer is set to false,
`config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false`

Comment: That is not the issue as it is set to true. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place I would look is the smtp settings in your environments, check to make sure that is correct:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => 587,
:domain => "gmail.com",
:authentication => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:user_name => "youremail@gmail.com",
:password => "yourpassword"
}
config.action_mailer.default_charset = "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

I use an old ruby, 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8, so check to make sure the syntax is correct as well.

Comment: @JakeGould: I've edited the twin `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors` out.

Answer (score 5):

I spend much time for sending email using delayed jobs, finally it works.

In Gem File

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

In Controller

```
 def dtest

    UserMailer.delay.welcome_email
    render json:"Succes"
    return
 end
```

In mailer

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def welcome_email
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp 
        ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
                address: "smtp.gmail.com", 
                port: 587, 
                domain: 'gmail.com',
                Authentication: "plain", 
                enable_starttls_auto: true, 
                user_name: 'your@gmail.com',
                password: 'yourpassword'
            }

    mail(to: 'no-reply@gmail.com', subject: 'Background Email Test').deliver

  end

end
```

After this I just start rails server and start job work

```
rake jobs:work
```

I hope, It will help you guys and Email sending will work fine using 'delayed-jobs' :)

Comment: Note that this approach works well for Rails v. <= 4.1

Comment: Also need to run the generator and migration: `rails g delayed_job:active_record` and
`rake db:migrate`